Openssl Provider integrate with NGINX
I have written AES provider for encryption/decryption. This provider is in the form of a .so library stored in the /usr/lib/ossl-modules path.
I want to do a session handshake encrypted using this AES Provider.
For that, I want to use the nginx configuration. I can see in the latest nginx code, the "nginx" term is used in openssl_config file.
Can anyone help how to call (load) the OpenSSL config file with my implemented provider from the nginx config?
What changes need to be made on the nginx side and what command is needed to load the OpenSSL configuration file?
Also, what specific change needs to be made in the OpenSSL config file so that nginx can identify and load this provider?
